# improving fitting results of neural network

Tags: regression, machine-learning, matlab, neural-networks, fitting

I've trained fitnet network for prediction steel's yield stress with MATLAB `ann` toolbox.

The neural network should predict yield stress. I have about 250 vector inputs. Every input vector has 12 parameters as inputs plus one parameter as target (yield stress).
`ann` should predict yield stress.

The inputs are weight percent of chemical elements that are used in steel.

Here is my code snippet:

```
inputs=transpose(inputs);
targets=transpose(targets);

net =  feedforwardnet(20);
%net.trainParam.max_fail=1000

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Train the Network
[net, tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

Here are the `ann` training results:
[image]
Here is the regression plot:
[image]

Here is the actual output (green) and neural network output (red) charts in one diagram:

[image]

As it can be seen the charts are not overlapping. This means that network has not worked well.

How can I improve results? Should I use other network or topology. Is my data very noisy or incorrect or they are less to train `ann`?
I've taken data from here:

http://www.msm.cam.ac.uk/map/data/materials/welddb-b.html

Comment: Have you tried something simpler than a neural network first, like linear regression? If not you should. It looks like you're using 20 hidden units which means you'll be fitting 12 * 20 (input to hidden) + 20 (hidden biases) + 20 (hidden to output) + 1 (output bias) = 281 parameters using 250 data points.

Comment: i didn't use linear regression. this is a prediction/learning problem. Is 20 neurons much or less what you mean by number 281 ?

Comment: Linear regression is applicable to prediction problems. If you removed the hidden units and just had input to output weights in your ANN, you would have a linear regression model. 20 hidden units may be too many, but you should determine empirically, for example using cross-validation, not by guessing. The 281 number comes from the number of free parameters in the ANN, there is a weight from every input to every hidden unit (12 * 20), every hidden unit to every output unit (20 * 1), 20 hidden biases and 1 output bias.

Comment: @alto thanks for your useful comments. i think its because of my data that the net does not train well.

Comment: @alto: I've trained net with other data set (with 20 parameters and 30 hidden layer neurons). now i have regression over 97.0 and in last figure i have improved results. their is still a vibration over and below target (red line vibrates)!!!?